# find files from directory if exist or not exists

Tags: shell, find, diff

I have a file having multiple lines of files. I also have a directory wherein i have all the files, now I want to find the files which are listed in a file exists in directory or not via shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and test

```
cat filelist.lst | while read filename
do
   if [ -f directory/$filename ]
   then echo File $filename exists
         # build up a list
        exists="$exists directory/$filename"
   fi
done
```

Comment: i want if file exists the echo exists and if file dont exists the echo file not found.

Comment: Add an else statement and another echo